# best websocket client javascript library for nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket

I tried with 'ws', I am able to connect; after few seconds; I am getting closed message;

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

var url = 'wss://wsocket.com:443/api/svc/v1/org/live';

const webSocket = new WebSocket(url, {
  perMessageDeflate: false, 
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic Yndpbm5ld2NvbTAwMDAwMTp0ZXN0MTIz`,
  },
});

webSocket.on('open', function open() {
  console.log('Connection has been established.');
});

webSocket.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('message received:'+ message);
});


webSocket.on('error', function(code, reason){
    console.log('error occured: code'+ code +' reason: '+ reason );
});


webSocket.on('close', function(code, reason){
    console.log('client closed: code'+ code +' reason: '+ reason );
});
```

Is there any other websocket libraries providing clean API or how to get this work with 'ws'

Please Before down vote, give me a reason; if you didn't understand the question;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket.io works great. check it out... easy to work with and smooth setup.

Comment: Thanks for reply; could you please provide a working sample example; if you have handy

Comment: socket.io has a very basic howto which will help you get started https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: I didn't find client code & example does not accepting headers;

Comment: Could you please provide an example with headers & url as input params for client; I am totally new to this stuff;